# kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL -9806 suspected ATS failure

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, firebase, app-transport-security

A ~8-month app has suddenly stopped launching properly and the Xcode 10.2 simulator delivers a blank screen with the following error immediately upon launch:

```
CFNetwork internal error (0xc01a:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CFNetwork_Sim/CFNetwork-808.2.16/ProjectRuntime/CFNetworkInternal.h:481)
2017-02-08 00:29:37.223[99834:1670390] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
```

The break point is in the 3rd line below, which has been in place for months in AppDelegate.m's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
[FIRApp configure];
[FIRDatabase database].persistenceEnabled = YES;
[[PropertyAPI sharedInstance] setFIRref: [[FIRDatabase database] reference]];
```

For clarity, the above code has not changed for months and tested well on devices in 2016 and all iPad and iPhone simulators.

To debug a suspected ATS failure, as described [here](http://timekl.com/blog/2015/08/21/shipping-an-app-with-app-transport-security/), this is what I received from Log after setting the environment variable CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS:

```
2017-02-08 00:34:22.068 [APPNAME][2557] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000001] Configuring the default app.
2017-02-08 00:34:22.077381 [APPNAME][2557:683996] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3404000 started
2017-02-08 00:34:22.081 [APPNAME][2557:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3404000 started
2017-02-08 00:34:22.082159 [APPNAME][2557:683996] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
2017-02-08 00:34:22.082 [APPNAME][2557:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
2017-02-08 00:34:22.083642 [APPNAME][2557:683935] Firebase Crash Reporting: Successfully enabled
2017-02-08 00:34:22.085183 [APPNAME][2557:684000] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2017-02-08 00:34:22.085 [APPNAME][2557:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2017-02-08 00:34:22.085524 [APPNAME][2557:683992] CFNetwork diagnostics log file created at: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B94912CB-B7DB-4CA8-9D0A-28FFA268CB94/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/CFNetwork_[appID]_2557.nwlrb.log
2017-02-08 00:34:22.085600 [APPNAME][2557:683992] CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:1] 00:34:22.083 {
LoaderWhatToDo: (null)
       Request: <CFURL 0x1700d37f0 [0x1adb5fbb8]>{string = https://play.googleapis.com/log, encoding = 134217984, base = (null)}
   CachePolicy: 1
      WhatToDo: originload
   CreateToNow: 0.00201s
} [3:1]
2017-02-08 00:34:22.086847 [APPNAME][2557:684002] CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:2] 00:34:22.086 {
AddCookies Continue: request POST https://play.googleapis.com/log HTTP/1.1
       HTTPProtocol: Task: 5fd0c200
} [3:2]
2017-02-08 00:34:22.087305 [APPNAME][2557:684002] CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:3] 00:34:22.087 {
DiskCookieStorage Construction: Binary{ Disk Cookies: { /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B94912CB-B7DB-4CA8-9D0A-28FFA268CB94/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies, <0 cookies in 0 domains> clean not writing } }
                     Accessing: <CFURL 0x1740baca0 [0x1adb5fbb8]>{string = file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B94912CB-B7DB-4CA8-9D0A-28FFA268CB94/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies, encoding = 134217984, base = (null)}
                          Path: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B94912CB-B7DB-4CA8-9D0A-28FFA268CB94/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
                Read from disk: <0 cookies in 0 domains>
                         Dirty: NO
                       Writing: NO
                        Policy: 2
} [3:3]
2017-02-08 00:34:22.087579 [APPNAME][2557:684002] CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:4] 00:34:22.087 {
DiskCookieStorage Journaling On: Binary{ Disk Cookies: { /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B94912CB-B7DB-4CA8-9D0A-28FFA268CB94/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies, <0 cookies in 0 domains> clean not writing } }
                           File: <CFURL 0x1700bc7a0 [0x1adb5fbb8]>{string = file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B94912CB-B7DB-4CA8-9D0A-28FFA268CB94/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies, encoding = 134217984, base = (null)}
} [3:4]
2017-02-08 00:34:22.087978 [APPNAME][2557:684002] CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:5] 00:34:22.087 {
HTTPCookieStorage::copyCookiesForURL: <CFHTTPCookieStorage 0x170091440 [0x170091450]>
                         Request URL: https://play.googleapis.com/log
                    MainDocument URL: NONE
} [3:5]
2017-02-08 00:34:22.088430 [APPNAME][2557:684002] CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:6] 00:34:22.088 {
Protocol Enqueue: request POST https://play.googleapis.com/log HTTP/1.1
         Request: <CFURLRequest 0x1701bc7e0 [0x1adb5fbb8]> {url = https://play.googleapis.com/log, cs = 0x0}
         Message: POST https://play.googleapis.com/log HTTP/1.1
         Sending: dict [6] {
                      Content-Encoding: gzip
                                Accept: */*
                          Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
                        Content-Length: 225
                       Accept-Language: en-gb
                       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
                  }
} [3:6]
2017-02-08 00:34:22.088607 [APPNAME][2557:684002] CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:7] 00:34:22.088 {
SocketStream IO Logging: (null)
} [3:7]
2017-02-08 00:34:22.088930 [APPNAME][2557:684002] 2557: CFNetwork internal error (0xc01a:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-808.3/ProjectRuntime/CFNetworkInternal.h:481)
2017-02-08 00:34:22.089324 [APPNAME][2557:684000] CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:8] 00:34:22.089 {
TCP Connection Start: (null)
          Connection: 0x174188130
       Connection ID: 1
} [3:8]
2017-02-08 00:34:22.110: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2017-02-08 00:34:22.110: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"
2017-02-08 00:34:22.110441 [APPNAME][2557:684000] CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:9] 00:34:22.110 {
TCP Connection Connected: (null)
              Connection: 0x174188130
           Connection ID: 1
                   Error: 0
} [3:9]
2017-02-08 00:34:22.127949 [APPNAME][2557:683992] CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:10] 00:34:22.127 {
Authentication Challenge: (null)
                  Loader: <CFMutableURLRequest 0x1741bc000 [0x1adb5fbb8]> {url = https://play.googleapis.com/log, cs = 0x0}
               Challenge: challenge space https://play.googleapis.com:443/, ServerTrustEvaluationRequested (Hash 9c5b8dc48d973537)
} [3:10]
2017-02-08 00:34:22.173: <FIRMessaging/INFO> FIRMessaging library version 1.2.0
2017-02-08 00:34:22.177225 [APPNAME][2557:683992] CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:11] 00:34:22.176 {
LoaderWhatToDo: (null)
       Request: <CFURL 0x1700d5540 [0x1adb5fbb8]>{string = https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin, encoding = 134217984, base = (null)}
   CachePolicy: 0
      WhatToDo: originload
   CreateToNow: 0.00031s
} [3:11]
2017-02-08 00:34:22.177736 [APPNAME][2557:684002] CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:12] 00:34:22.177 {
AddCookies Continue: request POST https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin HTTP/1.1
       HTTPProtocol: Task: 5fd18ba0
} [3:12]
2017-02-08 00:34:22.177879 [APPNAME][2557:684002] CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:13] 00:34:22.177 {
HTTPCookieStorage::copyCookiesForURL: <CFHTTPCookieStorage 0x170091440 [0x170091450]>
                         Request URL: https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin
                    MainDocument URL: NONE
} [3:13]
2017-02-08 00:34:22.178417 [APPNAME][2557:684002] CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:14] 00:34:22.177 {
Protocol Enqueue: request POST https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin HTTP/1.1
         Request: <CFURLRequest 0x1701bd500 [0x1adb5fbb8]> {url = https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin, cs = 0x0}
         Message: POST https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin HTTP/1.1
         Sending: dict [5] {
                               Accept: */*
                       Content-Length: 274
                         Content-Type: application/json
                      Accept-Language: en-gb
                      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
                  }
} [3:14]
2017-02-08 00:34:22.182617 [APPNAME][2557:684002] 2557: CFNetwork internal error (0xc01a:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-808.3/ProjectRuntime/CFNetworkInternal.h:481)
2017-02-08 00:34:22.183535 [APPNAME][2557:684000] CFNetwork Diagnostics [3:15] 00:34:22.182 {
TCP Connection Start: (null)
          Connection: 0x1741886e0
       Connection ID: 2
} [3:15]
2017-02-08 00:34:22.200: <FIRMessaging/WARNING> FIRMessaging AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification receiver handlers. Add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
(lldb)
```

But unlike the helpful [link (already mentioned above)](http://timekl.com/blog/2015/08/21/shipping-an-app-with-app-transport-security/), I do not see the "underlying error code" it describes in the aforementioned article:

> While this error doesn’t include a description, we see that the
>   underlying error code is -1202 rather than -9824.

In the console notes above, all I can see is a few null values and I do not understand the implications:

> TCP Connection Connected: (null)

and

> SocketStream IO Logging: (null)

and

> LoaderWhatToDo: (null)

After considerable time, I am not making progress on this and welcome any help someone can offer in terms of advice or recognising what is going on here.

For completeness, I add the info.plist details for NSAppTransportSecurity dict:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>play.googleapis.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <string>YES</string>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>device-provisioning.googleapis.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <string>YES</string>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

EDIT:

Thanks @Wottle.  Correct guess: something had changed.  A single line: a recursive call in the app's initialising method (which sets the in-app's 'default user settings' during 1st installation) created a time-out.  Apple app review suggested it was possibly a ATS network issue (perhaps because it timed-out during network log-in?).  I followed and created a wild-goose chase for myself.  I need to raise another query because some network errors in the above diagnostics still appear for some reason.  Here is my [newly-raised question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149734/wkwebview-does-not-display-public-weebly-html-page).

Comment: The URL in the code already is HTTPS. "https://play.googleapis.com/log HTTP/1.1" so I think you no longer needs NSExceptionDomains entries.

Comment: Your first line disables ATS altogether, so your exception domains are irrelevant, unless you intend to turn on ATS for those domains. It looks instead like you are trying to disable ATS for everything and also for the google domains (redundant).  Your errors are probably due to something else.  You say your code hasn't changed, but something in the build pipeline has.  New version of Xcode? New base SDK?

Comment: Also, just as a suggestion, replace your two exception domains with a single googleapis.com domain exception (with the existing settings, including the `NSIncludesSubdomains` set to true.  That will handle your two existing entries, as well as any other googleapis subdomains you may need in the future.  Also, you need to isolate what has changed between when it worked and now that it doesn't.  See my previous comment.